# Unable to set cookie on localhost:3000

Tags: php, cookies

I am running a react app on localhost:3000. I made an axios request to my backend on the default XAMPP localhost to setcookie. In previous attempts, I am able to setcookie if my frontend is in the default XAMPP localhost. But since switching to the react dev server, localhost:3000. I am unable to set cookie.

Here is my php file:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require __DIR__ . './vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

if(isset($_POST)){
    //grab secret key from .env file, remember to exclude from gitignore.
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
    $dotenv->load();
    $key = $_ENV['SECRET_KEY'];

    //access post data to for jwt creation
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kuching');
    $expiry = new DateTime();
    $expiry->setTimezone($timezone);
    $expiry->modify("+2 days");
    
    $date = $expiry->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.v");
    $payload = array(
        "ttl"=>$date,
        "data"=>$data['tokenValue']
        
    );
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload,$key);
    setcookie("accessToken",$jwt,[
        'expires'=>$date,
        'path'=>'/',
        'domain'=>'localhost',
        'secure'=>false,
        'httponly'=>true,
        'samesite'=>'None'
    ]);
    
}
```

What could be wrong? I did change the domain from 'localhost' to 'localhost:3000' but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472554/cookies-not-sent-by-browser-on-same-server-with-different-port).

First on the react app, in the axios method, do this:

```
axios
  .post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {
    withCredentials: true,
}).then(....)
```

You need to add credentials true header in the request header. Do the same in the php file.

At the beginning of the file do this,

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

Before, access-control-allow-origin is set to *. But for the sake of setting a cookie for localhost:3000, we do so. Also include the allow-credentials, because we send the axios request withCredentials true.

It should work now.